# Moving an element in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Given I have a linked list, and I want to move a given node to the end of the list, is there a more elegant way of doing this, than what I've done here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
  int val;
  struct node *next;
} node_t;

void insert(node_t **head, int val)
{
  node_t *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  node_t *tmp;

  new_node->val = val;
  new_node->next = NULL;

  // Empty list?
  if(*head == NULL) {
    *head = new_node;
    return;
  }

  tmp = *head;

  while(tmp->next != NULL)
    tmp = tmp->next;

  tmp->next = new_node;
}

void movetoend(node_t **head, int val)
{
  node_t *curr;
  node_t *tmp = NULL;
  node_t *old = NULL;

  // Find val in list
  for(curr = *head; curr != NULL; old = curr, curr = curr->next) {
    if(curr->val == val) {
      // Matched node is the only one in the list, don't do anything
      if(curr->next == NULL)
        return;

      // Matched node is first, set next to jump over
      if(old == NULL)
        *head = curr->next;

      // Matched node is in the middle, set next to jump over
      else
        old->next = curr->next;

      // Set a pointer to matched node for later use
      tmp = curr;

      // Loop through the rest of the list
      // "old" will have the pointer to last node
    }
  }

  // No matches?
  if(tmp == NULL)
    return;

  // Terminate list
  tmp->next = NULL;

  // Append matched node
  old->next = tmp;
}

void print(node_t *head)
{
  while(head) {
    printf("%d\n", head->val);
    head = head->next;
  }
}

int main()
{
  node_t *head = NULL;

  insert(&head, 10);
  insert(&head, 20);
  insert(&head, 30);
  movetoend(&head, 10);
  print(head);

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Added comments, modified movetoend function a bit slimmer.

Answer (score 1):

There's more *elegant* ways, although not necessarily more *efficient*. The common idiom for fiddling with this kind of linked list in C is to add one more layer of indirection and fiddle with pointers-to-node-pointers, like this:

```
void insert(node_t **head, int val)
{
    node_t *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    new_node->val = val;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    node_t **ptmp = head;
    while (*ptmp != NULL) {
        ptmp = &(*ptmp)->next;
    }
    *ptmp = new_node;
}
```

Given that example, I think you can figure out how to rewrite `movetoend` in just a few additional lines: much shorter than the page of code you have now.

However, whether this will be *equally fast* depends on your compiler and optimization levels. When in doubt, check the assembly code! If you see a lot of additional memory loads in the inner loop, that's a bad sign.

In C++, but *I think* not in C yet, you could eliminate even the *appearance* of extra memory loads by doing

```
void insert(node_t **head, int val)
{
    node_t *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    new_node->val = val;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    node_t **ptmp = head;
    while (node_t tmp = *ptmp) {
        ptmp = &tmp->next;
    }
    *ptmp = new_node;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   for(curr = *head; curr != NULL; old = curr, curr = curr->next) {
>     if(curr->val == val) {
> ```

I'd consider

```
  // iterate until we find val or run out of nodes
  for (curr = *head; curr != NULL && curr->val != val; old = curr, curr = curr->next) ;

  if (current == NULL) {
      // no matches -- nothing to move
      return;
  }

  if (current->next == NULL) {
      // already at end of list -- no need to move
      return;
  }

  // remove current from list
  if (old == NULL) {
      // current at the beginning of the list
      *head = current->next;
  } else {
      old->next = current->next;
  }

  current->next = NULL;

  for (old = old->next; old->next != NULL; old = old->next) ;

  old->next = current;
```

Now we don't need `tmp`.

Also, we don't iterate over `curr` when we just want to change `old`.

I prefer the block form of control structures.  I find it easier to read, and it is more robust in the face of future changes.

But I used the statement form for the two empty `for` loops.

I prefer to write out `current`.

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant way of doing this.  Make `insert()` more efficient.

Rather than use a `NULL` terminated linked list, have the tail point to the first element (*head*).  Also have the pointer to the linked list point to the last element - so it becomes the *tail* pointer.  Net effect, a circular linked list.

Consider `insert()`.  1) Allocate to the size of the referenced data,not the type.  This is easier to code right, maintain and review. 2) Test the allocation.  3) Notice **`insert()` now has no loop!**  It is now `O(1)` rather than `O(n)`.

```
int insert(node_t **tail, int val) {
  node_t *new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node);
  if (new_node == NULL) return FAIL; 
  new_node->val = val;

  if(*tail) {
    new_node->next = (*tail)->next;
    (*tail)->next = new_node;
  } else {
    new_node->next = new_node;
  }
  *tail = new_node;
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

`void movetoend()`  needs a similar re-write to employ this new approach. It will remain `O(n)`.  Further, it should return a value indicating `SUCCESS` (found) or `FAIL` (not found).

`void movetoend()` could be coded calling 2 helper functions: `int append(node_t **tail, int val)` and `int remove(node_t **tail, int val)`.  `int append(node_t **tail, int val)` is *very similar* to `insert()` and also `O(1)`.

`print(node_t *head)` re-write.

```
void print(const node_t *tail) {
  if (tail) {
    const node_t *ll = tail->next;
    while (printf("%d\n", ll->val), ll != tail) {
      ll = ll->next;
    }
  }
}
```